# Email Action Not available in Salesforce Service Cloud Publisher Layout

Tags: email, service-cloud-console, servicecloud, publisher-action, publisher

**I have added email action to case publisher layout below is the screenshots -** 
[image]

**But it is not available in case feed publisher layout, see below screenshots-** 
[image]

Please Help.

Comment: is that my answer solves your purpose?  I didn't heard anything after posting my answer

Answer (score 2):

Email button is not showing since you are using global email action in the Quick Action.

If you can closely look into the properties, you will see like this.

[image: Send email target object outgoing]

1. Remove that action from page layout
2. Go to Support Settings and choose `Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items` :

[image]

3. When you select this option, you will go the feed based page layout and will see a **new Email action** is getting displayed with the **same label**.

   > - Label - Email
   > - Name - Case.Email
   > - Action Type - Email

[image: Case.Email]

4. Use that Email Action and you will see like this:

[image: Email action]

Comment: No Its did not solve my problem, Still i didn't able to see the email publisher. its might be some other reason. Sorry for late reply.